# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un atributo de un elemento HTML en que hacemos clic en Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular5

Estoy usando *Angular 5.2*.

***Intento hacer lo siguiente:***

Tengo varios elementos HTML cada uno con un evento de tipo clic que invoca a un mismo método del componente. Este método recibe un string que usa internamente. Es decir que en el template HTML tendría algo así:

```
<p class="link" id="id_1" (click)="xxx('foo')">click 1</p>
<p class="link" id="id_2" (click)="xxx('baz')">click 2</p>
```

y en la clase del componente:

```
public xxx(element: string): void {
    console.log('value: ' + element);
}
```

Lo que quiero es poder pasar, automáticamente, el valor de un atributo del elemento HTML, en este ejemplo un párrafo, que puede ser por ejemplo su ID.

***He probado con:***

```
<p class="link" id="id_1" (click)="xxx(this.id)">click 1</p>
<p class="link" id="id_2" (click)="xxx([attr.id])">click 2</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías directamente poner el valor que quieres:

```
<p class="link" id="id_1" (click)="xxx('foo')">click 1</p>
<p class="link" id="id_2" (click)="xxx('baz')">click 2</p>
```

Lo que, asumiendo que esos elementos los creas con un bucle, podrías escribirlo así:

```
<p *ngFor="let elem of elems; let i=index" class="link" (click)="xxx(elem.attr)">click {{i}}</p>
```

Esto es suponiendo que tengas en el componente algo como

```
this.elems = [{attr : 'foo'}, {attr : 'baz'}];
```

Con lo que realmente el campo `id` no te haría falta (llevo trabajando con Angular más de un año y nunca he usado el `id` para buscar elementos)

Si aun así quieres acceder al elemento en sí, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<p class="link" id="id_1" (click)="xxx($event.target.id)">click 1</p>
```

Y en el componente usa:

```
xxx (id) {
   console.log('value: ' + id);
}
```

Comment: Lo tengo así ahora mismo (paso de los valores directamente), en espera de respuesta. Los ids: `id_1` e `id_2` los he puesto a título ilustrativo, bien podría ser `foo` y `baz`, tampoco estoy generando los elementos dinámicamente. Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: *En espera de respuesta* ¿A qué te refieres?

Comment: De cómo obtener automáticamente el valor de un atributo del elemento, como por ejemplo su id, para no tener que ponerlo yo mismo.

Comment: Te he actualizado poniendo lo que pides, aunque realmente no le encuentro mucha utilidad. El uso del DOM cuando trabajas con Angular no es muy necesario

Answer (score 0):

Prueba pasar el atributo event dentro de la función: `(click)="xxx(event)"`
Después crea la función en la clase del componente que recibe ese evento

```
function xxx(e){
    console.log(e.target)
}
```

Dentro de target tienes todos los eventos que recibe

Comment: No se puede crear una función en la clase de Angular con la palabra `function`, obviando esta palabra y si creo el método como indicas, el resultado es: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`